# Extracting Data from Raster based on Aspect Raster file

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing

I have 2 rasters, ones shows aspect and another shows date of snow thaw. I want to extract the date of snow melt based on values from the aspect raster. For example I want all the snow thaw dates from south facing slopes. I have already identifies north (1), east(2), south(3), west(4). I have tried to extract the values:

```
snowThawSouth <- extract(aspect==3, snowThawDate)
```

However I just got the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "RasterLayer"’
In addition: Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (/var/folders/4_/9jsy7tfj2yq0s_czc2gc6tvh0000gn/T/R_raster_USER//2015-07-17_152719_21839_88030.gri)
```

I just want to be able to extract all the values for each aspect, into a list, in order to compare the snow thaw dates based on the aspect of the cell.

Comment: do you just want the values or do you want it as separate rasters?

Comment: I just need a list of the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extract` pulls raster values out based on an intersection with a vector. That could be helpful if you wanted to sample raster values given something like a points shapefile. In this case, however, you want a to identify the cells based on value, and then get the data directly from the raster. This may need to be modified if performance in reading the data is an issue:

```
# Get the indexes which represent the different aspects. 
# These correspond to the cell indexes for north, east, etc.
idxNorth <- which(getValues(aspect)==1)
idxEast <- which(getValues(aspect)==2)
idxSouth <- which(getValues(aspect)==3)
idxWest <- which(getValues(aspect)==4)
```

We can use those indexes to extract the data directly into a vector:

```
snowThawNorth <- getValues(snowThawDate)[idxNorth]
snowThawEast <- getValues(snowThawDate)[idxEast]
snowThawEast <- getValues(snowThawDate)[idxSouth]
snowThawWest <- getValues(snowThawDate)[idxWest]
```

As @JeffEvans notes, these can be nested for brevity:

```
snowThawNorth <- getValues(snowThawDate)[which(getValues(aspect)==1)]
snowThawEast <- getValues(snowThawDate)[which(getValues(aspect)==2)]
snowThawEast <- getValues(snowThawDate)[which(getValues(aspect)==3)]
snowThawEast <- getValues(snowThawDate)[which(getValues(aspect)==4)]
```

Comment: You can nest even further by just applying the which index directly: snowThawNorth <- getValues(snowThawDate)[which(getValues(aspect)==1)]

Comment: Thanks worked a treat. Apologies for not marking the question answered until now.